# How to get correct decimal answer in java

Tags: java, decimal

Eg: I divide manually `8/3 = 2.666666`.

When I divide in Java, I've got `8/3 = 2.0` instead.

How can I get the answer to display `2.667` or `2.67`?

Thank you.

Comment: Most people do integer division in primary school before fractions and decimals, but they seem to forget it. How do you explain to a Grade 4 student that they should remember this when they start learning Java in 10+ years. ;)

Answer (score 1):

You are doing integer division hence result is integer

you need to do `((double)8)/3` to get desired result

Comment: Or shorter in this case since literals are used `8d/3`

Comment: Alternatively, `8./3`.